# How do I login to Wechat on Windows without QR code?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8-apps, qr-code

I have Wechat installed on an iOS device (iPad) and on my Windows 10 PC. The usual way to log in on Windows (the app/program, not the web application) is to scan the QR code that shows up on my screen with the Wechat app on my iPad.

How can I log in on Windows without the iPad? Or is this impossible?

I'm thinking of using the phone number, email adress or Facebook account connected to my Wechat (all of which I have access to), but I can see no login options other than the QR code.

Answer (score 0):

If you logged in before, it might automatically log you back in. Otherwise, you MUST scan the QR code with your mobile device, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is also tormenting a large number of Chinese WeChat users, and there is a lot of criticism about it on the Chinese internet, which has even been ongoing for many years. BUT, unfortunately, there is no way to log in to WeChat without scanning the QR code with your phone, unless:

- You have already scanned and logged in on this computer before.
- AND, you have logged in to WeChat on this computer within the past 3 days.

Then you can click "log in" on the computer without scanning or inputting anything, otherwise, you have to scan with phone.